# Using the now() function and executing triggers

Tags: postgresql, triggers, timestamp, infinite-loop, plpgsql

I am trying to create a trigger function in PostgreSQL that should check records with the same `id` (i.e. comparison by `id` with existing records)  before inserting or updating the records. If the function finds records that have the same `id`, then that entry is set to be the `time_dead`. Let me explain with this example:

```
INSERT INTO persons (id, time_create, time_dead, name)
VALUES (1, 'now();', ' ', 'james');
```

I want to have a table like this:

```
 id  time_create  time-dead  name
 1   06:12                   henry   
 2   07:12                   muka
```

`id 1` had a `time_create 06.12` but the `time_dead` was `NULL`. This is the same as `id 2` but next time I try to run the `insert` query with same id but different names I should get a table like this:

```
 id  time_create  time-dead  name
 1   06:12        14:35      henry   
 2   07:12                   muka
 1   14:35                   waks
```

henry and waks share the same `id` `1`. After running an `insert` query henry's `time_dead` is equal to waks' `time_create`. If another entry was to made with id 1, lets say for james, the time entry for james will be equal to the `time_dead` for waks. And so on.

So far my function looks like this. But it's not working:

```
CREATE FUNCTION tr_function() RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
  IF tg_op = ''UPDATE'' THEN
     UPDATE persons
     SET time_dead = NEW.time_create
     Where
         id = NEW.id
         AND time_dead IS NULL
         ;

  END IF;
  RETURN new;
END
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER sofgr BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
        ON persons FOR each ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE tr_function();
```

When I run this its say `time_dead` is not supposed to be `null`. Is there a way I can write a `trigger function` that will automatically enter the time upon `inserting or updating` but give me results like the above tables when I run a `select` query?

What am I doing wrong?

My two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE temporary_object
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  time_create timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  time_dead timestamp without time zone,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, time_create)
);

CREATE TABLE persons
(
  name text
)
INHERITS (temporary_object);
```

Comment: The first problem is you can't update a table inside a trigger that fires on update of this same table. That would cause an infinite recursion.

Comment: Can you include the definition of the table?

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko just a minute

Comment: @DanielVérité: Of course you *can* do that. It's your responsibility, though, to prevent infinite recursion. I added a clause to prevent that ..

Comment: I cleaned up the question and fixed contradictions in your setup to make the example work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Trigger function

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION tr_function()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   UPDATE persons p
   SET    time_dead = NEW.time_create
   WHERE  p.id = NEW.id
   AND    p.name <> NEW.name
   AND    p.time_dead IS NULL;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;
```

You were missing the `INSERT` case in your trigger function (`IF tg_op = ''UPDATE''`). But there is no need for checking `TG_OP` to begin with, since the trigger only fires on `INSERT OR UPDATE` - assuming you don't use the same function in other triggers. So I removed the cruft.

You don't have to escape single quotes inside a dollar-quoted string.

Also added:

```
AND    p.name <> NEW.name
```

... to prevent `INSERT`'s from terminating themselves instantly (and causing an *infinite recursion*). This assumes that a row can never succeed another row with the same `name`.

Aside: The setup is still not bullet-proof. `UPDATE`s could mess with your system. I could keep updating the `id` or a row, thereby terminating other rows but not leaving a successor. Consider disallowing updates on `id`. Of course, that would make the trigger `ON UPDATE` pointless. I doubt you need that to begin with.

#### `DEFAULT now()`

If you want to use `now()` as default for `time_create` just make it so. [Read the manual about setting a column `DEFAULT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html). Then skip `time_create` in `INSERT`s and it is filled automatically.

If you want to *force* it (prevent everyone from entering a different value) create a trigger `ON INSERT` or add the following at the top of your trigger:

```
IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
    NEW.time_create := now();   -- type timestamp or timestamptz!
    RETURN NEW;
END IF;
```

That forces the current timestamp for new rows unconditionally.
(Assuming your column "time_create" is actually type [`timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).)

Comment: my insert query is not runing if leave one timestamp value null

Comment: @theuserkaps: You need to be way more specific than that. Edit your question if it's more than a simple comment.

Comment: @theuserkaps: That's short for `persons AS p` and `p` is a table alias. Look for "alias" [in the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html).

Comment: ooh ya,one other thing i have been trying to modify the function above such that when i run insert query i should not put time_create value as now but when i just insert the values the time_create should always be automatically use the function now(); inside the function,is there a way i can do it??thanks

Comment: thanks you have really been helpful im very greatful i have learned alot from you thanks

Comment: sorry for troubling you but i think the query u added is not doing the what the previous one did its just putting the time automatically