# Trigger to update current date using "standard" SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

The answer to a [decade-old StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494625/trigger-to-update-current-date-in-postgres-9) was helpful for me. However, I was unable to write an equivalent function and trigger in "standard" SQL, i.e. where the `language` parameter specifies `sql` instead of `plpgsql`. The hangup appears to be that functions written in standard SQL can't return triggers, though this appears to be required for functions called by triggers in [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html):

> The trigger function must be declared as a function taking no arguments and returning type trigger.

So attempting...

```
create function func_dummy()
returns trigger as
'update tbl_dummy
set update_date = current_timestamp;'
language sql;
```

results in:

```
ERROR:  SQL functions cannot return type trigger
SQL state: 42P13
```

How can the PostgreSQL-specific function and trigger in the [original SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494625/trigger-to-update-current-date-in-postgres-9) be rewritten using "standard" SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can the PostgreSQL-specific function [...] be rewritten using "standard" SQL?

That's not possible. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/triggers.html)

> Trigger functions can be written in most of the available procedural
> languages  [...]
>
> It is also possible to write a trigger function in C, although most
> people find it easier to use one of the procedural languages. It is
> **not currently possible to write a trigger function in the plain SQL function language**.

Bold emphasis mine.

I have written thousands of trigger functions. Almost all of them with `LANGUAGE plpgsql`.

Related:

- [Using the now() function and executing triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765930/using-the-now-function-and-executing-triggers/13770247#13770247)
- [Timestamp can't be saved as epoch number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330835/timestamp-cant-be-saved-as-epoch-number/13330967#13330967)

Comment: You can write a function with language SQL, but it **cannot** be a trigger function.  A trigger function must **return ...** either Null or a  tuple matching the row from the table. An language SQL function cannot issue return statement.